# VSTO C# - How to edit a .xltx file and don't save it as new file

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vsto

I can't figure out why this isn't working with a XLTX file. My code is wokring quite well with XLSX files.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Copies the template file and renames the new one.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="sourceFilePath"></param>
    private void CopyTemplateFile(string sourceFilePath)
    {
        string strSheetName = "";
        DialogResult result;

        result = MyDialog.ShowDialog("New File - Dialog", "Bitte Name eingeben", "Neue Datei erstellen?", "=FOR1+RBT1", "Ok", "Cancel", ref strSheetName);

        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)     
        {
            SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
            sfd.Filter = "Excel Template (*.xltx)|*.xltx|Excel File (*.xlsx)|*.xlsx";
            sfd.FileName = strSheetName;
            DialogResult ergebnis = sfd.ShowDialog();

            if (ergebnis == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string path = sfd.FileName;                                                 
                //string tmp = path.Substring(path.LastIndexOf('\\')+1);
                System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFilePath, path);


                Excel.Application app = new Excel.Application();
                Excel.Workbook wb = app.Workbooks.Open(path, ReadOnly: false);
                Excel.Worksheet ws = (Excel.Worksheet)wb.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
                ws.Name = strSheetName;                                                 
                ws.Range[Statics.ANLAGE_ORT_CELL].Cells.Value2 = "'" + strSheetName;                        
                string stAnlage = strSheetName.Substring(1);                            
                string[] abc = stAnlage.Split('+');                                     
                ws.Range["A50"].Cells.Value2 = abc[0];                                  
                ws.Range["B50"].Cells.Value2 = abc[1];                                  
                wb.SaveAs(path);
                wb.Close();
                app.Quit();
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(app);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, a open file dialog for `sourceFilePath`, a save file dialog for `path`. The changes of sheet.name and cell values aren't saved if a XLTX is used.
Maybe someone of you guys knows the issue.

Comment: You run `wb.SaveAs()` without giving a path? How can Excel know where to save then? So it should either be `wb.Save()` or give a path (and filename) for `SaveAs()`.

Comment: oh I'm sorry. It was wb.Save() but somewhere I saw a solution with wb.SaveAs() without a path and I gave it a try. But this also didn't work.

Comment: Did you try `SaveAs` specifying the path **and** the [fileformat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat) (`xlOpenXMLTemplate`)? That should actually work. Have a look into the documentation of the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas)

Comment: Got a COMException: 
Additional information: This extension cannot be used with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the 'File Name' text box, or choose a different file type by changing the 'Save As' selection.

Comment: What code *exactly* did you use? Please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: Please see my second comment again and read the linked documentations. `wb.SaveAs(path);` specifies a path but not a file format! You need to specify both correctly. If you filename ends with `.xltx` it needs to be of fileformat `xlOpenXMLTemplate`.

Comment: wb.SaveAs(path, FileFormat: Excel.XlFileFormat.xlOpenXMLTemplate); does the trick. So, you're right! I actually don't know why xlOpenXMLTemplate is the correct one but I will find out. Thank you very much PEH ! Please answer my question to get your rightful reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is this line:

```
wb.SaveAs(path);
```

According to the documentation of the [Workbook.SaveAs method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas) you can/should give the following parameters:

- `FileName`
  A string that indicates the name of the file to be saved. You can include a full path; if you don't, Microsoft Excel saves the file in the current folder.
- `FileFormat`
  The file format to use when you save the file. For a list of valid choices, see the XlFileFormat enumeration. For an existing file, the default format is the last file format specified; for a new file, the default is the format of the version of Excel being used.

Actually both are optional, but if you omit the `FileName` Excel will use the standad file name and the "current folder" who knows which one this is, and if you omit the `FileFormat` then Excel would use the last file format that was specified or for new files the standard format which is a normal xlsx (in recent versions of Excel).

Another thing is that the file extension you use `.xltx`, `.xlsx`, `.xlsm` necessarily needs to fit the correct file format. If it doesn't Excel throws an error. This is actually what you run into when you got the Error:

> COMException: Additional information: This extension cannot be used
>   with the selected file type. Change the file extension in the 'File
>   Name' text box, or choose a different file type by changing the 'Save
>   As' selection.

Because you only specified the `FileName` and you chose `.xltx` as file extension but the default file format is usually `xlOpenXMLWorkbook` according to the list in [XlFileFormat enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat).

So if you lookup in that list which file formats you can use with the extension `.xltx` then you will only find one valid file format and that is `xlOpenXMLTemplate`. So this is what you need to specify:

```vb
'example for path/filename you got from your dialog box
path = "C:\YourPath\YourFileName.xltx"

wb.SaveAs(FileName:=path, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLTemplate);
```